# Install OpenGL 4.0+ in Ubuntu 14.04 running by a VM

Tags: vmware

I tried to build a project using Qt 5.0 and OpenGL 4.0+. I had successfully installed Qt 5.0. But, it comes problem when I install OpenGL 4.0+. I have used `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` to check my version. It shows

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
```

I look up some materials on the internet that if I want to run OpenGL 4.0+, it needs to detect your graphic card like NVIDIA. I'm not sure how do I solve the problem when using VMware player.

btw: my laptop is equipped with a NVIDIA GeForce 840M graphic card and Intel CPU i7-4700HQ.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use OpenGL 4.0 in a virtual machine.

VM does not directly interact with the hardware. That's why you can't use a proprietary Nvidia driver.

You will be able to use OpenGL 4.0+ in Ubuntu, if you install it directly without any virtualization.